# Check Backendless database

Tags: java, android, backendless

We started working with Backendless and I am trying to check if the database is empty before I can register the user. I want to do this because the first user should have a different value than the others.

How can I test the Backendless database to see if it is empty?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just run a `findFirst()` call against the `Users` table. If the result is `null`, then it means the table is empty.